# Wordpress template shown after migration to new web host

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I migrated my Wordpress website from Godaddy to Hostgator.

Here's what I did:

1. Made a dump of the db using PhpMyAdmin
2. Copied every single files from my www/ folder (including the .htaccess)
3. Pasted those copied file to the new host www/ folder
4. Created a new MySQL db and user on new host
5. Updated the wp-config.php file with new db name and user info.
6. Ensuring path in data are ok (new host use /home2 instead of /home)
7. Since we have 2 domain name which one was unused, I pointed that one to the new nameservers host so I can try everything works fine
8. Ensure in db data it uses the second domain name (unused until now)

So both website are similar, same files same db but hosted at two different places.

The expected result is: http://dsi-ing.com

But currently, nothing from the db is loaded and what is shown is the bare theme without any of my modification or data...

You can see it for yourself at: http://dsi-ing.ca

I can't access the wp-admin section too. And same thing when I try to access /wp-login.php

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

- Did you check PHP error logs?
- You may turn WordPress in debug mode (set `define ( 'WP_DEBUG', true )` in the file `wp-config.php`.

You should then know if there is a problem with the database access, filesystem permissions or missing files.

Comment: Yes I did that but nothing shows in the error_log. And debug.log shows the following warning (which is for a plugin): [25-Nov-2017 01:56:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  wpcf7_add_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_add_form_tag instead. in /home2/dsiadm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351

Comment: If there is no error reported, it would mean WordPress read/write the database nicely. Try to take an overall look on the new database and check if indices are indentical to the old database or at list consistant (primary keys matches foreign keys). Your DB import might broke things.

Comment: I just checked your new site back. Lots of "Table does not exist". Did you just empty your new database ?

Comment: And it's working! Thanks for pointing me into the right direction! Yes, the db dump script was wrong and stuffs were missing.

Yeah I emptied my DB probably right when you tried it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in the DB SQL dump file generated by PhpMyAdmin. Once fixed, everything worked fine!